# How can I find a value in 4 tables?

Tags: sql, inner-join, union

I have 4 tables in sql developer (TABLE, TABLE1, TABLE2 and TABLE3) and I would like to know if a certain value exist in one of this 4 tables (for example TIE = 100).

The 4 tables have the same structure with "TIE" column.

I would like to know in which table the TIE value equals 100.

I have written this in sql, but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT TIE ,
  instr
FROM
  (SELECT TABLE1.TIE,
    'terre' instr
  FROM TABLE,
    TABLE1
  )
UNION
  (SELECT TABLE2.TIE,
    'air' instr
  FROM TABLE,
    TABLE2
  )
UNION
  (SELECT TABLE3.TIE,
    'mer' instr
  FROM TABLE,
    TABLE3
  )
WHERE TIE = '100';
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You've got the right idea, using UNION. However, what are you trying to accomplish by cross joining `TABLE` and the other three tables at each point, instead of including a fourth section, unioning in the fourth table? Also, when asking questions, wouldn't it make sense to define what "doesn't work" means?!!

Comment: if I remove the condition "where" I have several results , while, according to my tables, I should have one . The " WHERE" condition is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query might give the required result :-

```
 select TIE,instr
 from
 (
 SELECT TIE,'terre' instr
 FROM TABLE

 UNION

 SELECT TIE,'terre' instr
 FROM TABLE1

 UNION

 SELECT TIE, 'air' instr
 FROM  TABLE2

 UNION

 SELECT TIE,'mer' instr
 FROM  TABLE3

 ) A where TIE=100
```

Comment: This isn't right, you take from `TABLE1` twice, and omit `TABLE`. I'm sure it was just a typo so I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT TIE , 'terre' instr
FROM TABLE
WHERE TIE = '100'
UNION
SELECT TIE , 'terre' instr
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TIE = '100'
UNION
SELECT TIE, 'air' instr
FROM TABLE2
WHERE TIE = '100';
UNION
SELECT TIE, 'mer' instr
FROM TABLE3
WHERE TIE = '100';
```